# What's the purpose of the components shown in this circuits?

Tags: power

I have a question when studying a power switch circuits.
As shown in the picture below.
It's an switch to enable 12V and 5V to the system by EN signal.
My questions are:

1. What's the purpose of C2, C4, C5?
2. What's the purpose of D1, D2, R3, R4?

Thanks a lot for any reply! :)

BR,
David Wu

[image]
Hi Olin:

Thanks for the detailed feedback! :)
I still got few questions about your answer and hope that you can give me some hints.... 
Add more pictures for discussion.

1. For C2/C4/C5, you said that they are there for slop control.
   I add another picture to show the possibe charging current.
   Take Q3 and Q4 for example, did you mean that due to the existance of C4 and C5, the voltage built on drain node of Q3 and Q4 will be lower than not having C4/C5?
   Same idea for Q2?
   How about the turn-off slop?  Still controlled by discharging this C ?
   (See pic 1 and 2 below)

   There comes a another question, when Q3 and Q4's gate go high, will it boost the drain at the same range, due to C4/C5 existance? Will drain voltage exceed 12V then? (same situation when Q3 from off to on, will drain be coupled to negative voltage first?)
2. For Diodes, I think you mean that they are used to make charging/discharging time symmetrical.
   Charging : 12V => 4.7K => D => Q3 gate
   Discharging : Q3 gate => 100K => Q2 on resistor
   Not sure if the resistor value make sense to balance the timing.
   (See pic 3 below)
3. Is C3 there only for compensate the charging time of Q2's gate?
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Thanks a lot for all the helps!!

David

Comment: 1. It is used to filter AC/Noise signal as the transistors will act as current amplifiers.
2. Diodes and resistors are there to limit the current in the gate of the transistors (useless, should probably only put a 100 ohms resistor instead).

Comment: Hi Lucas, you mean the C over gate/drain is to filter the AC noise with switching?

Comment: @Shao-WeiWu  Where did you find this circuit? Is it just to provide a soft start for 12V, 5V to reduce inrush current? or synchronize power sequence?  Pd in output FET will equal load as it pulls up slow. Change for spurious resonance is high with high gm and reactive load.

Comment: @Tony Stewart This is the circuits of a server platform board. It's used for SATA power switch only. I think it's for soft start purpose, just want to know the detail operation for these capacitors. What's Pd you mentioned? Is it power dissipation?

Comment: The only problem I see is the 12V switch has no bootstrap Vgs   so it cannot pull up Source to 12V  , It should have been P Channel

Comment: I think it's PMOS now?

Comment: then they both must be Pch and diodes reversed.. Is this in prototype stage?

Comment: It's still first version board.
Just want to discuss more.....
I don't know why you think the diode should be reversed with PMOS implemented?
Let's take Q3 for example.
When we want to turn on 12V, Q3's gate will be GND (pull down by Q2 turn on).
D1 is reversed biased all the time before Q3's gate is discharged to GND.

Comment: If we want to turn off 12V, let Q2 off, and charge Q3's gate.
D1 will be forward bias first, and then finally Q3's gate will be 12V, since there is no current at the end (anf I think D1 will be off then since the voltage on its two sides are both 12V).
Is that correct? Any reason you want D1 to be reversed?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Diodes In half bridges speed up turn off,  if that is what you want ok. But since Vcc is already ON EN input logic should be for fast synchronous turn on, otherwise how to control power sequence

Comment: When you mentioned power sequence, did you mean the sequence of 12v and 5v?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C2, C4, and C5 all slow down the switching edges.  These are probably a attempt at slope control.  Note that this kind of slope control lengthens the time the switching elements are kept in the transition region between full on and full off.  This can significantly increase dissipation, which needs to be taken into account in the design.

D1,R3 and D2,R4 cause the final switches to be turned off quicker than turned on.

The diodes conduct when the gate voltages are slewed up, which happens when the switches are turned off.  A forward biased diode will have roughly constant voltage across it, so the coupling from the output of Q2 to the gates has low impedance.

When the gate voltages is slewed down, the diode are reverse-biased.  This means they are in effect not there.  The resistors now couple the output of Q2 to the gates.  That, together with the gate capacitance and the extra deliberate capacitors C4 and C5, cause the switches to be turned on more slowly then they are turned on.

One reason for the asymmetry introduced by the diodes and their parallel resistors may be to compensate for the higher Q2 output impedance when driving high.  When Q2 is turned on, it actively drives its output low.  When turned off, that same node is only passively pulled up by R2.  Since values aren't shown, we can't tell if the slow rise due to R2 dominates, or the slow fall due to R3 and R4, or if they are roughly balanced.

Note that Q1 and R1 introduce yet another rise/fall asymmetry.  Q1 will actively drive its output low, which is then passively pulled up only by R1 to go high.  Again, without values we can't tell the relative strengths of these various asymmetries, and therefore which ones dominate, or whether they roughly balance each other out.

Comment: Hi guys, I add the R and C values on the schematics.

Comment: I got further questions, hopefully someone can help me out of there. :)